# Как сравнить два df и выбрать строки?

Tags: python, pandas, анализ-данных

Имеется два `df`:

df1

```
date        qw   er ty ui
2021.06.07  rtg  23 45 56
2021.06.07  rty  23 45 56
2021.06.07  req  87 89 09
2021.06.07  rew  98 09 98
2021.06.05  rew  98 45 67
2021.06.05  req  98 13 34
```

df2

```
date        qw   er ty ui
2021.06.07  rty  23 45 130
2021.06.07  req  87 89 50
2021.06.07  tre  98 09 98
```

Как корректно сравнить оба `df` и сделать выборку строк из 2го `df`?

Результат выборки должен выглядеть следующем образом:

```
date        qw   er ty ui
2021.06.07  tre  98 09 98
```

Если по основным условиям, сравнивать текущую дату, соответсвенно, где значения `qw   er ty` в двух df одинаковые, не попадают в выборку, только новые, попытки соединить и выполнить `query` запрос, к сожалению, не увенчались успехом.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
res = (df2
       .merge(df1, on=["date", "qw", "er", "ty"], indicator=True, how="outer", suffixes=["", "_1"])
       .query("_merge == 'left_only'")
       .dropna(axis=1)
       .drop(columns="_merge"))
```

результат:

```
In [184]: res
Out[184]:
         date   qw  er  ty    ui
2  2021.06.07  tre  98   9  98.0
```